# Думается, что (?) да. Нужен ли какой-либо знак после "что"?

Tags: пунктуация

Контекст такой : "Встретимся ли вновь где-то? Думается, что(?) да".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед "да" не нужно никакого знака.

*— Встретимся ли вновь где-то?

— Думается, что да.*

Стоит отметить, что на подобный вопрос чаще всего отвечают "думаю". Если есть желание показать нерешительность или раздумье при ответе, то можно использовать многоточие.

— Встретимся ли еще когда-нибудь?
— Думаю, что... да.

Дополнение
Из заголовка: *Нужен ли **какой - либо** знак после “что”?*
Кто-либо, что-либо, какой-либо, чей-либо... — [дефис](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2730) пробелами не отделяется.